# How should I display a validation error detected by an ICellEditorValidator?

Tags: java, eclipse, validation, jface

I have a TableViewer with an ICellModifier which seems to work fine.  I set an ICellEditorValidator on one of the cell editors, though, and I can't get it to behave the way I would like.  Here's my abbreviated code:

```
cellEditors[1] = new TextCellEditor(table);
cellEditors[1].setValidator(new ICellEditorValidator() {
    public String isValid(Object value) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt((String) value);
            return null;
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            return "Not a valid integer";
        }
    }
});
```

It mostly works fine.  However, there are two issues:

1. The `modify` method of the cell
   modifier receives a null as the new
   value if the validator returns an
   error.  I can code to handle this,
   but it doesn't seem right.  Null
   could be a valid value, for example,
   if the user's picking a background
   color and they picked transparent.
   (This is a general issue, not specific to this example.)
2. The validator's error message is
   never displayed to the user.  This
   is the big problem.  I could also
   add an ICellEditorListener and
   display a dialog from the
   `applyEditorValue` method if the
   last value was invalid.  Is this the
   "proper" way to do it?

By the way, for reasons beyond my control, I'm limited to the Eclipse 3.0 framework.

Answer (score 9):

you can add a listener to your Editor:

```
cellEditors[1].addListener(
        public void applyEditorValue() {                    
            page.setErrorMessage(null); 
        }

        public void cancelEditor() {
            page.setErrorMessage(null);                 
        }

        public void editorValueChanged(boolean oldValidState,
                boolean newValidState) {                    
            page.setErrorMessage(editor.getErrorMessage());                                 
        }
```

With *page* being your current *FormPage*, this will display the errorMessage to the user.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the second issue, the string the validator's method `isValid` returns becomes the error message for the `CellEditor` owning that validator. You can retrieve that message with `CellEditor.getErrorMessage`.

It appears to me that the easiest way to show the error message is through a `ICellEditorListener`, as Sven suggests above. Maybe the tricky thing about this listener is that the cell editor is not passed as a parameter to any of its methods, so the assumption is that the listener knows which cell editor is talking to it.

If you want the dialog, the preference page or whatever object to implement the `ICellEditorListener` interface you have to be sure it knows the cell editor being edited.

However, if it's the cell editor itself which implements the interface it should have a way to properly carry the error message over into the dialog, the preference page or whatever. That's the `currentForm page` Scott is looking for.

One last thing worth noticing if you're using `EditingSupport` is that the value passed into the `EditingSupport.setValue` method is null when `ICellEditorValidator.isValue` returns an error message. Don't forget to check it out.